# Как найти убывающий столбец в матрице

Tags: golang, матрицы

```
package main

import "fmt"


func main() {
    array:=[4][4]int {{2,1,6,5}, {7,6,8,0},{4,6,3,1},{5,6,7,4}}
    b:=0;
    for i:=0;i<4;i++{
        for j:=0;j<5;j++{
            if  array[i+1][j]<array[i][j] {
                b=b+1
            }
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(b)
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Уточню , что нужно найти количество убывающих, мой код выходит за пределы массива

Comment: 1) Какой язык программирования? Проставьте тэг. 2) Нумерация индексов у вас явно с нуля, значит для массива длиной 4 допустимые индексы это 0, 1, 2, 3. Индекс i+1 в случае i = 3 - выход за пределы массива. Индекс j = 4 - выход за пределы массива.

Comment: Ну и сама проверка - вы должны убедиться, что **весь** столбец убывает, т.е. делать какую-то проверку внутри первого цикла. Я такой проверки не вижу. Есть как минимум два варианта, как это можно сделать.

Comment: Язык программирования go

Comment: ты не мог бы нормально форматировать код. Невозможно смотреть.

Comment: @Эникейщик Я за неё отформатировал, но там же и так всё понятно

Answer (score 1):

```
    array:=[4][4]int {{2,1,6,5}, {7,6,8,0},{4,6,3,1},{5,6,7,4}}
           ^^^^^^
    b:=0;
    for i:=0;i<4;i++{
        ^^^^^^^^
        for j:=0;j<5;j++{
            ^^^^^^^^
            if  array[i+1][j]<array[i][j] {
                     ^^^^^^^^
                b=b+1
            }
        }
    }
```

Размер массива 4x4, но индексация начинается с 0, а значит валидные индексы это 0, 1, 2, 3.

На последней итерации цикла по `i` у вас будет `i = 3`, а значит обращение к `array[i+1][j]` будет по индексу `array[3+1][j]`, выход за пределы массива.

На последней итерации цикла по `j` у вас будет обращение к `array[i+1][4]` - снова выход за пределы массива.

Значит, оба цикла нужно заканчивать чуть раньше, чтобы не выходить за пределы массива.

Что касается сути задачи, то вы, например, можете считать кол-во убывающих элементов во внутреннем цикле, что вы сейчас и делаете. Только `b` нужно обнулять перед началом внутреннего цикла, а после внутреннего цикла нужно проверять, что `b` совпадает с числом итераций внутреннего цикла и в этом случае можно увеличивать счётчик убывающих столбцов, для чего вам нужно завести ещё одну отдельную переменную. Можно и по-другому это делать - завести перед внутренним циклом флаг и сбрасывать его, если условие убывания не выполняется хотя бы один раз. После цикла проверять это условие и менять или не менять счётчик уменьшающихся столбцов.